# Why can't I concatenate a value in the second part of the ISNULL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've already solved this issue using a CASE statement, but I'm wondering why, when using `ISNULL`, can I concatenate a value to the check_expression but not the replacement_value. Here's an example:

```
create table name_test 
(
    nm          varchar(25)
    ,mid_init   varchar(1)
    ,name_type  int
)

insert into name_test values('Joe',NULL,1)
insert into name_test values('Joe','X',2)
```

I have this query.

```
SELECT
    n1.nm, isnull(n2.mid_init+'b',n1.mid_init) as m1,
    isnull(n1.mid_init,n2.mid_init+'b') as m2
FROM 
    name_test n1
    JOIN name_test n2 
    on n1.nm = n2.nm and n1.name_type = 1 and n2.name_type = 2
```

In the first statement (`m1`), I use the NOT-NULL value first, concatenated with a 'b'. In the second statement (`m2`), I use the NULL value first, so the query should pass through to the replacement_value. It does, but only takes the first value, not the concatenated value.

Result:

```
nm     m1   m2
Joe    Xb   X
```

With a little more investigation, I see that this query:

```
select 
    n1.nm, isnull(n2.mid_init+'b',n1.mid_init) as m1,
    isnull(n1.mid_init,'1'+ n2.mid_init+'b') as m2
from 
    name_test n1
    join name_test n2 
    on n1.nm = n2.nm and n1.name_type = 1 and n2.name_type = 2
```

returns

```
nm  m1  m2
Joe Xb  1
```

So, the `ISNULL` function will take the entire `check_expression`, but if the `check_expression` is null, it will only take the first part of the `replacement_value`.

Does anyone know why there is a discrepancy. Also, I solved it with a case - is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ISNULL` inherits the data type of the first expression, while `COALESCE` inherits the data type according to data type precedence. (What is the point of `varchar(1)` anyway?)

I would do:

```
select n1.nm, 
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), n1.mid_init),'1'+ n2.mid_init+'b') as m2
from name_test n1
join name_test n2 on n1.nm = n2.nm and n1.name_type = 1 and n2.name_type = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. That is a better way to do it.

Comment: But, I am still curious about why this happens, since it treats the two arguments differently.

Comment: If you just say `ISNULL(mid_init, some other expression)` then both expressions are converted to the data type of the first. Since `mis_init` is `varchar(1)`, the output (and second expression) will also be `varchar(1)`. What is `CONVERT(varchar(1), 'xyz')`? `x`.

Comment: Thanks - I see my mistake. Appreciate the help.